# ZooKeeper - command zkCli doesn't connect

Tags: homebrew, apache-zookeeper

When I ran the command zkCli, I got the following output:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0] ls /
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 1]
```

I use homebrew install and services start zookeeper,and it successfullly started! 
`zkServer status` shows below

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
Client port found: 2181. Client address: localhost.
Mode: standalone
```

```
echo srvr | nc localhost 2181
echo srvr | nc 127.0.0.1 2181
```

print

```
Zookeeper version: 3.5.6-SNAPSHOT--1, built on 02/27/2020 03:01 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/0
Received: 1
Sent: 0
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xe02
Mode: standalone
Node count: 83
```

`zoo.cfg`
this file need add something?

homebrew installation path is `/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.5.7/bin`
echo prints `Zookeeper version: 3.5.6-SNAPSHOT--1` version have problem?

---

Now I tail `zookeeper.log` and find out exception

```
2020-06-08 18:36:36 ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:296)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1104)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1139)
2020-06-08 18:36:36 NIOServerCnxn [WARN] Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket
```

Comment: Your zkCli shows `CONNECTING` state. Please check, that your Zookeeper is up and running (and that you open cli only after successfully starting Zookeeper).

Comment: You can also check status of your cluster/instance by running `echo srvr | nc localhost 2181` or `./zkServer.sh status`.

Comment: I have solved this problem, upgrade JDK from version 8 to version 11

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure, that your Zookeeper instance is up and running **before you try to connect** to it.

To check status of Zookeeper execute:

```
zkServer status
```

Output should be similar to:

```
Client port found: 2181. Client address: localhost.
Mode: standalone
```

If it doesn't work, please check:

- If there is anything in Zookeeper log file
- Your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. You can also run `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` (on macOS) to be sure it is correct.
- That ports are not used: `lsof -i :2181`, `lsof -i :8080` (both ports can be configured in `zoo.cfg` by changing `clientPort` and `admin.serverPort` respectively)

Comment: Can you help me look at the problem again? I posted some logs